# How to find the last modifed date and time of a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, sqlconnection

I have get to the point where the connection is open and able to display database name...

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring_here"))
            {
            try    
            {

            connection.Open();
            DBname.Text=connection.Database;

            } 
            catch (Exception) 
            { 
            /*Handle error*/ 
            }
            }
```

I see on MSDN that there is this "table" class and its last modified date is `tb.DateLastModified.ToString()`

How do I get to that given where I get to?

Comment: "How do I get to that give where I get to?" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I suppose.. your question is somewhat unclear to me.  Are you attempting to look up when a record was last modified, when a database is last modified, or when your connection is establish? I'll tell you right now though, SO isn't really intended to a place where you're told the basics of doing ADO.NET..

Comment: Last modified means what exactly? The structure or data? (i.e are you talking about CRUD operations here?)

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea to put a try catch in a using statement.. without putting a final block that ensures the closing of the connection.

Comment: actually.. that might be the other way around.. I'm really just pointing out there are points of consideration when you use both like this..

Comment: Hi I want to find the last modified date for a table in the database. I now found that I need to use server class and use ServerConnection class to get the actual database and table as objects? Please advise if this is the right path.

Comment: You could also get it directly from the database with a query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is SQL Server Management objects.

1. Add a project reference
2. Browse to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\
3. Add reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

You should now be able to follow the MSDN guidance and use a table object.

Comment: Yep I see it now, because currently I'm getting the error "The type or namespace name 'ServerConnection' could not be found". I'm assuming I need the DLLs in order to use ServerConnection? This is more work than I expected but I guess there is no other way to get the table property (modified date) without using Smo correct?

Comment: Not that I know of. And I would imagine there are some parts for the internals of SQL Server that might still make the answer unreliable. 

If you are worried about the freshness of data, querying the last update of the table is not your best bet anyway. Consider adding date field(s) to the data.

Comment: Gregory, just wondering, what are your thoughts on finding the last modified time using sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats and its last_user_update column for the database?

Comment: @photonacl - It is a possibility, but there are queries that do not use indexes, for one reason or another, so it is not 100% accurate. It is a good table to use to see which indexes are being hit, as there is a counter value in there.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the input. I think it is not 100% ideal so I will find some other solutions. Thanks again.